# Dynamic pointers passed as parameter cpp

Tags: c++

Hi  I am facing trouble with dynamic pointer's as I am getting undefined refrence error.
Here is my segmentof code :

```
void FlyingUnit::addFall( const char* location, int day, int month, int year )
{
    if(fallCount >= MAX_FALLS)
    {
        cout<<"Cannot add MAX_FALLS raggiunti ";
    }
    else
    {

        falls[fallCount].setLocation(location); //Dynamic pointer problem
        falls[fallCount].setDay(day);
        falls[fallCount].setMonth(month);
        falls[fallCount].setYear(year);
        fallCount++;
    }

}

void Fall::setLocation(const char* location)
{
    if( this->location != nullptr )
    {
        delete [ ] this->location;
    }

    this->location = new char[ strlen(location)+1 ];
    strcpy( this->location, location);  
}
```

Comment: What is a _dynamic pointer_? Undefined reference is a linker error message, did you stich all your object files and libraries together properly?

Comment: @Slava its called B++ and is the predecessor of C++

Comment: @Slava Dude I am kidding!!

Comment: ah... you ate not OP ... overseen that. Got me there

Comment: yes I have included  all header files but getting problem with pointer attributes

Comment: Can you add the error message too?

Comment: @Anny could you please provide us the header file  ?

Comment: @Anny post your header file for Fall (I assume it's Fall.h), maybe the function declaration and definition don't match?

Comment: @Anny _"I have included all header files"_ common misconception, including the header files isn't actually enough. You also need to provide all the build artifacts and library dependencies to the linker command line.

Comment: @adnan_e if it is does match then it would not compile.

Comment: @Slava If i'm not mistaken, the issue here is that it doesn't compile (undefined reference might be just one of the errors)

Comment: following are my header file already defined 
#include "flyingUnit.h"
#include "fall.h"
#include "dragon.h"
#include "rider.h"

Comment: @adnan_e undefined refernce is a linker error so you cannot see it if it fails to compile.